# Conditionally define Property in WIX Fragment on dialog level

Tags: .net, windows, wix, windows-installer

Here you can see a Control in Dialog, that publishes properties conditionally. But the properties need to be accessible when dialog is shown, because other controls - TextBoxes, for example, use them.

How can I achieve that without messing with previous dialog's buttons?

```
    <UI Id="IdOfUI">
        <Dialog Id="IdOfDialog">
            <Control Id="IdOfControl" Type="PushButton" >
              <Publish Property="PROP" Value="1" Order="1"><![CDATA[PROP2 <> ""]]></Publish>
              <Publish Property="PROP" Value="2" Order="1"><![CDATA[PROP2 = ""]]></Publish>
              <Publish Property="PROP" Value="3" Order="1"><![CDATA[PROP2 = "" AND PROP3 = ""]]></Publish>
              ...
            </Control>
        </Dialog>
    <UI>
```

---

#### In the end I was able to solve it with builtin *SetProperty* *CustomAction*, That modifies *InstallExecuteSequence* and *InstallUISequence* under the hood.

> The tool [**Orca**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was veeery helpful - it shows the resulting sequences in msi

```
<Fragment>
    <Property Id="PROP1" />
    <Property Id="PROP2" />

    <SetProperty Id="PROP1" Action="SetPROP1_0" After='AppSearch' Value="VALUE1" ><![CDATA[PROP1 <> ""]]></SetProperty>
    <SetProperty Id="PROP1" Action="SetPROP1_1" After='AppSearch' Value="[VALUE2]"><![CDATA[PROP1 = "" AND VALUE2 <> ""]]></SetProperty>
    <SetProperty Id="PROP2" Action="SetPROP2_1" After='SetPROP1_0' Value="[PROP1]"></SetProperty>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Means, you have to set properties in advance (presumably in those "previous dialogs"), there is nothing like "form.onload" event in windows installer.

That's the zen of it - "designed by the most enlightened architectural astronauts, implemented by the worst coders" (c) - that's a sad joke of course, but partially true.. One must be really enlightened to make us design user interface using relational database tables.

Comment: FWIW, MSI was released in the summer of 1999 which means it was probably designed around 1997.  Back in those client-server day, I'm old enough to remember it :),  making code "data-driven" was all the rage and table data in a database was the way to do it.  XML and JSON weren't a thing yet.  MSI was invented by the Office team and they had flat file databases available to them to use.  It made perfect sense.  Today we have AppX which is storage with an XML manifest.  Same concept really only they ditched the UI completely.

Answer (score 1):

MSI dialog behavior is that the publishes aren't in scope until you transition to the next dialog.  So the the usual workaround is to split your controls onto different screens.   WiX maintenance UI (Repair, Change, Remove) works this way.  Instead of using a Radio and staying on the same screen they use Push buttons that publish then transition to the next dialog where they can be used.  You can also then put pretty icons on the buttons which you can't do with a radio selection.

Comment: FWIW, learning to do MSI UI in WiX is pretty hard. I'd suggest an eval copy of InstallShield or similar tool on a VM to get your feet wet.  Once you have it all working translate it to WiX.   Or buy a copy of InstallShield. :)   I do a lot of  WiX authored merge modules consumed by an InstallShield Basic MSI project  to leverage the best of both worlds.